# Kubernetes Container Environment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I wrote deployment.yml file in k8s:-

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: consul
    image: xyz
    ports:
      - name: http
        containerPort: 8500
      - name: http1
        containerPort: 53
    env:
    - name: SERVICE_8500_IGNORE
      value: "true"
    - name: CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG
      value: "{"node_name": "docker","acl_datacenter": "dc1", "acl_default_policy": "deny", "acl_down_policy": "deny", "acl_master_token": "fleeture", "acl_agent_token":"xyz", "enable_script_checks": true}"
```

After running I am getting errors

> Error : Unexpected characters near "node_name": "docker","acl_datacenter": "dc1", "acl_default_policy": "deny", "acl_down_policy": "deny", "acl_master_token": "xyz", "acl_agent_token":"xyz", "enable_script_checks": true}"".
>   Line : 14  value: "{"node_name": "docker","acl_datacenter": "dc1", "acl_default_policy": "deny", "acl_down_policy": "deny", "acl_master_token": "fleeture", "acl_agent_token":"xyz", "enable_script_checks": true}"

Any Idea how to write ENV for line 14?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `\` to escape the double-quotes within the value for `CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG` so that entry becomes:

```
- name: CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG
  value: "{\"node_name\": \"docker\",\"acl_datacenter\": \"dc1\", \"acl_default_policy\": \"deny\", \"acl_down_policy\": \"deny\", \"acl_master_token\": \"fleeture\", \"acl_agent_token\":\"xyz\", \"enable_script_checks\": true}"
```

Answer (score 2):

@ryan-dawson's answer is valid answer.

Also, you can simply replace first double-quote(**"**) with single-quote(**'**) as

```
- name: CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG
  value: '{"node_name": "docker","acl_datacenter": "dc1", "acl_default_policy": "deny", "acl_down_policy": "deny", "acl_master_token": "fleeture", "acl_agent_token":"xyz", "enable_script_checks": true}'
```